# Best practices when pulling API data that is being updated/changed repeatedly

Tags: python, api, quickbooks-online

currently I'm pulling data from the Quickbooks online API, parsing it and storing it into a database. My problem is, right now with the small amount of data I am pulling I am just deleting my db tables and repopulating the tables with the updated - is there any way I can do this more optimally?

Comment: In an ideal world, there would be an API that would let you pull a diff between two points in time. In terms of what to do in the world we're actually in, that depends on your design constraints and what's cheap or expensive for you. Are reads from your database cheap, writes expensive, and CPU readily available? Maybe you diff the active data against what the API pulled and build the smallest possible set of incremental changes... but whether that's the right thing is _very_ contingent on the details of your use case we aren't privy to.

Comment: (Personally, I'm a big fan of databases that store history and allow time-based queries, and for those, you _very much_ want to implement a diff algorithm... but again, this depends on the local database you chose / how you designed it / etc; also, your backup processes matter: If you're storing PostgreSQL transaction logs to allow point-in-time recovery, f/e, rewriting data over and over will bloat them... but if you don't do any of that, it may not matter).

Comment: Also, see [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354) at [meta.se].

Answer (score 1):

QuickBooks provides an API that is *exactly* what you're looking for. It's called `Change Data Capture` and is a common pattern for time-based updates like you're describing.

If you refer to Intuit's docs they tell you all about it:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/learn/explore-the-quickbooks-online-api/change-data-capture

Basically you make requests like this, providing a `date/time` you want data changed since:

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<realmId>/cdc?entities=<entityList>&changedSince=<dateTime>
```

And you get back a list of changed objects that you can then update your local database with:

```
{
    "CDCResponse": [{
    "QueryResponse": [{
        "Customer": [{
            ...
            "Id": "63",
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
            "Id": "99",
            ...
    }],
    "startPosition": 1,
    "maxResults": 2
    },
    {
        "Estimate": [{
            ...
            "Id": "34",
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
            "Id": "123",
            ...
        },
        {
            "domain": "QBO",
            "status": "Deleted",
            "Id": "979",
            "MetaData": {
                "LastUpdatedTime": "2015-12-23T12:55:50-08:00"
        }
    }],
    "startPosition": 1,
    "maxResults": 3,
    "totalCount": 5
    }]
    }],
    "time": "2015-12-23T10:00:01-07:00"
}
```